# How to pluralize "There is/are N object/objects"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Pluralizing a single word is simple:

```
pluralize(@total_users, "user")
```

But what if I want to print "There **is/are** N user/users":

> There are 0 users
>   There is 1 user
>   There are 2 users

, i.e., **how to pluralize a *sentence***?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can add a custom inflection for it. By default, Rails will add an `inflections.rb` to `config/initializers`. There you can add:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular "is", "are"
end
```

You will then be able to use `pluralize(@total_users, "is")` to return is/are using the same rules as user/users.

**EDIT**: You clarified the question on how to pluralize a sentence. This is much more difficult to do generically, but if you want to do it, you'll have to [dive into NLP](http://mendicantbug.com/2009/09/13/nlp-resources-for-ruby/).

As the comment suggests, you could do something with I18n if you just want to do it with a few sentences, you could build something like this:

```
  def pluralize_sentence(count, i18n_id, plural_i18n_id = nil)
    if count == 1
      I18n.t(i18n_id, :count => count)
    else
      I18n.t(plural_i18n_id || (i18n_id + "_plural"), :count => count)
    end
  end

  pluralize_sentence(@total_users, "user_count")
```

And in `config/locales/en.yml`:

```
  en:
    user_count: "There is %{count} user."
    user_count_plural: "There are %{count} users."
```

Comment: Actually, i think the question is more about how to interpolate the number of users, i.e. something which might look like a mix between i18n and pluralisation e.g. `pluralize(@total_users, "there is $1 user")`... which will obviously miserably fail :)

Comment: In [Agile Development with Rails, Fourth Edition](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails), page 217, they use `one` and `other` in the YAML file to pluralize error messages. This is used without any extra code to display the page errors, so it should work directly with `t()`.

Comment: One problem I hit with this solution is if you have a model that ends in 'are' (in my case ExtendedCare) all your code breaks

Answer (score 8):

This is probably best covered by the Rails i18n pluralization features. Adapted from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization

```
I18n.backend.store_translations :en, :user_msg => {
  :one => 'There is 1 user',
  :other => 'There are %{count} users'
}
I18n.translate :user_msg, :count => 2
# => 'There are 2 users'
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the first part of Martin Gordon's answer is pretty good.

Alternatively, it's kind of messy but you can always just write the logic yourself:

```
"There #{@users.size == 1 ? 'is' : 'are'} #{@users.size} user#{'s' unless @users.size == 1}."
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE to code:** I no longer use the inflections route as stated in @Martin Gordon's answer. For some reason it would cause other non-related functions to error. I did extensive tests to confirm, though could not track down a reason why. So, below is now what I use and it works.

There are many ways to do this. This is how I did it using Rails 6.0.3.4 and Ruby 2.7.1.

I wanted to pluralize this sentence:

- **Singular**: There is 1 private group
- **Plural**: There are 2 private groups

What I did is I went to `application_helper.rb` and added this code:

```
def pluralize_private_statement(list, word)
  num_in_list = list.count
  is_or_are = num_in_list == 1 ? 'is' : 'are'
  return "There " + is_or_are + " " + num_in_list.to_s + " private " + word.pluralize(num_in_list)
end
```

Now, all I have to use in my view is:

```
<%= pluralize_private_statement(private_groups, "group") %>
# private_groups = 2
# -> There are 2 private groups
```

What the code in `application_helper.rb` does is first create a variable for the number of items in the list passed and store it in `num_in_list`. Then it creates a second varible checking if the num_in_list is equal to 1 and if so returns 'is' otherwise it returns 'are'. Then, it returns the sentence that is constructed with the information obtained.

The first part of the sentence is a simple string, then the is_or_are variable which holds either 'is' or 'are' as explained above. Then it adds a space with the number of list items, converted from an integer to a string, followed by the 'private' word. Then it adds the pluralization of the word passed to the initial function; but, only returns the singular/plural word without a number attached as `pluralize(@total_users, "is")` would do.

**Here is how you could use it for your specific question.**

First, add this to your `application_helper.rb` file:

```
def pluralize_sentence(list, word)
  num_in_list = list.count
  is_or_are = num_in_list == 1 ? 'is' : 'are'
  return "There " + is_or_are + " " + num_in_list.to_s + " " + word.pluralize(num_in_list)
end
```

Lastly, you can use this code wherever you wish to have the pluralized sentence:

```
<%= pluralize_sentence(@total_users, "user") %>
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Instead, try this: `is_or_are = num_in_list != 1 ? 'are' : 'is'` and then you will also get the correct behavior for the zero case, i.e. `There are 0 users`